# Show an image in react native with resizeMode=cover but I want to chop off the bottom not top

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to show an image in react native with resizeMode=cover but I want to chop off the bottom not the top.

Currently this is what I have and it chops off the top:

```
          <Image
            source={myState.pictureSource}
            style={{
              resizeMode: 'cover',
              height: 200,
              width: '100%',
            }}
          />
```

**EDIT** with more info:
On a phone with a small width my image renders like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7eX2.png).
On a tablet with a wider width my image renders with the guys head chopped off like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFPTr.png). When I posted the question I wanted to push down the image so his head would be visible.

However, after thinking it through, maybe I should have just kept a fixed aspect ratio instead.

Comment: With such information people could not help you. Please share more detailed code of yours and also screenshot of image you wanted to chop off.

Comment: sadly you can't resize image like how you can resize in web. one way to do that is resize at server before pass to front end.

Comment: did you ever solve this image display issue?